# reactjs how to go to parent's route in nested routings

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say I access directly access from browser the URL

```
http://localhost:3000/developerList/developer/2
```

I will have a back button on the page that should go back to parent route, to

```
http://localhost:3000/developerList/
```

How can I achieve this? I can't use

```
history.goBack()
```

Because that triggers a browser back behavior, which actually goes back to google.com (assuming that's where I came from)

I also can't use

```
history.push('/developerList')
```

because that's not dynamic.

I know this can be done, froming from angular background where you can just do $state.go('^'); and it knows to remove the current route /developer/2 (yes, even the /2 part).

Any chance this can be done in react with libraries or i have to write something. For the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Here is the structure of my routings:

**App.js**

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/developerList'>
          <DeveloperListPage></DeveloperListPage>
        </Route>
      </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

**DeveloperListPage.js**

```
export class DeveloperListPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="developer-list-page">
        <Route path='/developerList/developer/:id'>
          <DeveloperPage></DeveloperPage>
        </Route>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and now in DeveloperPage I wish to have a go back functionality

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how you are organizing and structuring your routes (and presumably nested routes)?

Comment: @DrewReese here it is, let me know if it is enough

Comment: `goBack()` - (function) Equivalent to go(-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `DeveloperListPage` page/component level you can use the current route match to get the path that was matched to render it. Create a `gotoParent` callback function that uses a `history.push` to "go back" to this parent component.

Example Code:

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">/home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/developerList">/developerList</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/developerList">
          <DeveloperListPage />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

DeveloperListPage

```
const DeveloperListPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { path } = useRouteMatch(); // get matched path

  const gotoParent = () => history.push(path); // go to this path

  return (
    <div className="developer-list-page">
      <ul>
          <li>
            <Link
              to={`/developerList/developer/${Math.floor(
                Math.random() * 1000
              )}`}
            >
              /developerList/developer/:id
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <Route path="/developerList/developer/:id">
        <DeveloperPage gotoParent={gotoParent} /> // <-- pass callback
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};
```

DeveloperPage

```
const DeveloperPage = ({ gotoParent }) => { // <-- destructure callback
  const history = useHistory();
  const { id } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      Developer Page: {id}
      <div>
        <button onClick={gotoParent} type="button"> // <-- attach callback
          Go to parent
        </button>
        <button onClick={history.goBack} type="button">
          Go Back
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Demo

Initial URL: `"/developerList/developer/174"`

- Try the "Go Back" button
- Try the "Go to Parent" button and see difference

[image: Edit reactjs-how-to-go-to-parents-route-in-nested-routings]

**Note:** If you don't want to explicitly pass "gotoParent" callbacks to children routes you could easily abstract this into a React context to provide a "nearest" parent component to jump to.